# brew remove inkscape : Error: Calling needs :cxx11 is disabled

Tags: homebrew, inkscape

How can I fix the problem below ?

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
Already up-to-date.
Error: Calling needs :cxx11 is disabled! There is no replacement.
Please report this to the weikengchen/caskformula tap:
  /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/weikengchen/homebrew-caskformula/Formula/inkscape.rb:31

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  https://github.com/weikengchen/homebrew-caskformula/issues
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This finally fixed my problem:

```
brew untap weikengchen/caskformula
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Comment: Which Inkscape version does this yield?

Comment: I deleted `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskformula/homebrew-caskformula/Formula/inkscape.rb`, which at least seems to let med run update and upgrade

Answer (score 10):

Both the taps **caskformula/caskformula** and **weikengchen/caskformula** (possibly others?) seem to cause this problem. To list your current taps, run

`brew tap`

Now untap the suspicious repository:

`brew untap caskformula/caskformula` # This worked for me

Run `brew doctor` to check for issues after removing caskformula. If there are issues, follow the recommendations.

Finally update repositories and upgrade software:

`brew update`

`brew upgrade`

Some more info in this issue on github:

https://github.com/caskformula/homebrew-caskformula/issues/74